# Prove that if $G$ is abelian, then $H=\{a \in G | a^{n(a)}=e\}$ is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I was tackling this problem and I think I got only one part of the proof right. $n(a)$ is an integer and depends on $a$ 
To prove that the inverse is in $H$: 
$a \in H \Rightarrow a^{n(a)}=e \Rightarrow a^{-n(a)}a^{n(a)} = a^{-n(a)} \Rightarrow a^{-n(a)}=e \Rightarrow (a^{-1})^{n(a)} = e $ so $a^{-1} \in H$ 
As for the product closure, I'm stuck. Until now I got: 
$a,b \in H \Rightarrow  a^{n(a)}=e, b^{n(b)}=e \Rightarrow a=a^{1-n(a)}, b=b^{1-n(b)} \Rightarrow ab= a^{1-n(a)}b^{1-n(b)} =aa^{-n(a)}bb^{-n(b)}= ab $ 
Where I have used the fact that $a^{-n(a)}=e$ 
Anyway, as you can see, the result brings me nowhere.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what your subgroup is. Is it the subgroup of elements of finite order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $G$ is abelian, what is 
$$(ab)^{n(a)\cdot n(b)}= ?$$

Comment: It is $a^{n(a)}b^{n(b)} = e $ by the definition of the subgroup itself, so $(ab)^{n(a)n(b)} \in H $
I see now, so I could have just written the product like that?

Comment: @PeppeFabiano It is $$a^{n(a)\cdot n(b)} b^{n(a)\cdot n(b)}=\left( a^{n(a)}\right)^{n(b)}\left( b^{n(b)}\right)^{n(a)}$$

Comment: Right, I made a mistake, so it still follows that the product is equal to $e$ and thus $ab \in H$ right?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @PeppeFabiano Right.